# What is this sticker on the coolant expansion tank trying to tell me?

Tags: coolant, land-rover, lr3

My new-to-me Land Rover LR3 needs a coolant top-up.

The trouble is I don't know what this sticker on the reservoir (not cap) is trying to warn me about.

[image: Coolant tank]

Is the LR3 allergic to green coolant? Or is it warning against mixing different types of coolant?

I can already see green coolant in the reservoir, which adds to the confusion.

The manual just says to use a 50/50 blend of distilled water and Castrol SF Antifreeze. Nothing about green vs orange coolant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two kinds of coolant long life and conventional.

Conventional coolant uses silicate salts as a "preservative" per se. They help to reduce corrosion and what not.

Long life coolant uses organic acid to do the same thing. The organic acid lasts longer than the silicate salts.

Mixing the two kinds of coolant is not recommended. Adding long life to a conventional car is not that bad. Adding conventional to a long life degrades the long term performance of the long life.

Conventional coolant is always green. Long life coolant can be almost any color (green, orange, yellow are the most common, there is also blue).

The label is warning against mixing coolant. The car probably had orange in it from the factory. Then someone changed it to green. The real question is whether that's conventional or long life green and unless you have the empty bottles from when it was filled there is no good way to tell.

Comment: I wonder who was smart enough to think that green long life coolant was a good idea?

Comment: @njzk2 Probably someone who said "coolant is green, this is coolant, therefore we'll make it green".

Comment: What a wonderful opportunity to flush and fill the cooling system! You get a nice clean cooling system, AND you get some practice at a basic maintenance procedure! You should thank whoever it was that did this!